# Powershell script to open forms in dialog

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, modal-dialog

I have written some Powershell script to iterate through each subsite in a web application, the aim of the script is then to find a list in each subsite with a specific name.

For example, our lists are called "Team Messages" and my aim is to turn on the open forms in a dialog.

The script I have is:

```
 Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

# Get All Web Applications
$WebApps=Get-SPWebApplication
foreach($webApp in $WebApps)
{
    foreach ($SPsite in $webApp.Sites)
    {
       # get the collection of webs
       foreach($SPweb in $SPsite.AllWebs)
        {
            write-host $SPweb.title
               foreach($list in $web.Lists["Team Messages"])
               {
                    $list.NavigateForFormsPages = $false;               
                    $list.Update();                 
               }
        }
    }
  }
```

The code runs up to the final foreach loop where it then throws an error that is

> Cannot index into a null array.

If anyone could point me in the right direction with this then it would be great!

Comment: This error is basically telling you that `$list` is empty because `$web.Lists["Team Messages"]` is returning empty. I would ask you to check if that first returns any results, you might want to check the exact name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your site reference.

The `$web` reference in `foreach($list in $web.Lists["Team Messages"])` should actually be `$SPweb`

Also, confirm that the changes for modal dialogs have taken place as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work but it still doesn't set the forms to open in a dialog :( do you have any ideas with this please?

Comment: After running the powershell script, did you navigate to the list settings page for "Team Messages" list and confirm the change has taken place? I have added a screenshot of the page in my answer above.

Comment: Hi Ransher, yes I did however unfortunately it was still set to no. I will keep debugging the Powershell to see if I can get the botom of it, thank you for your help.